# Non existence of Continuous logarithm on $\mathbb{C}^*$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, logarithms

This is an exercise problem, which asks to prove the non-existence of continuous logairthm on $\mathbb{C}^*$, Using the results of path integrals, In that book they already proved the non-existence using the non-existence of continuous argument.

I tried to give a proof; I want someone to verify it

suppose there exists a continuous logarithm on $\mathbb{C}^*$, then by derivatives of inverse function theorem $\log^{'}(z)=\frac{1}{z}$, Now consider the path integral $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}$,where $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to \mathbb{C}$, such that $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$

As the primitive of $\frac{1}{z}$ exists, by the fundamental theorem of path integrals,
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}=\log(\gamma(1))-\log(\gamma(0))=0$$

But, we know that $$\int_\gamma\frac{1}{z}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{e^{it}}.ie^{it} dt$$
$$=2\pi i$$

And hence a contradiction.  Therefore there exists no continuous logarithm on $\mathbb{C}^*$.

Is this proof looks neat and fine, If not what's wrong, Kindly help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You wrote $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$ instead of $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to \mathbb{C}$. Except for this,  your proof is fine.

Comment: its fine but note that you are assuming more than just the fact that a continuous logarithm exists, you are assuming that a differentiable logarithm exists

Comment: @geetha290krm yes that's a typo. I shall correct that

Comment: @Masacroso I only assume the existence of continuous logarithm, it follows from the 'Derivatives of inverse function' theorem, that if there exists such a function then it is differentiable and its derivative is $\frac{1}{z}$. Isn't it?

Comment: @Praveen yes, It can be shown using the assumed continuity